# Cannot use right-click to delete Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

About 3 days ago,I update my AS,the version is now 1.5.
I often use Project not Android.But there is a problem since update.I cannot use double-click to open any Activity,And cannot use right-click to delete file,because this is grey.I don’t know why does it happened?
I search in Google,this is a solution : make the src folder as Souces Root.I try but it is not worked for me.
Then I switch the Android Tab,anything is OK.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Invalidate Caches/restart from File menu

Comment: @Survivor I try this way,but nothing has changed.T_T

Comment: I think this problem is a Bug,i commit this to https://www.gdgdocs.org/forms/d/13P9ZgqYdTANBr5ou8TT7jJ4FiixG8JFrPf0BfZXCBRE/viewform.
And when i reinstall,this problem is solve.

Comment: **Update:** last night,I update my AS(1.4.1)again,the version is 1.5.This problem is still.
I reinstall,but it cant solve.So,I update AS(1.5) to AS(2.0RC1).This problem is solved.